# Multiples IoT agents

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to use IOTA Manager and my question is the following: do I have to subscribe the IOTAs manually on IOA Manager? Is it possible for IOA manager auto-configuring automaticaly depending on the protocol ?

Comment: Question: you are developing an IOTA Manager? Or an IOTA (that you want to integrate with IOTA Manager). I'm asking because the usual case is to develop new IOTAs (adapted to specific southbound device technologies) but I don't see the point of developing a new IOTA Manager, taking into account there is the following one: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-manager

Comment: Instead of reformulating your question in a comment to the answer I'd suggest to do it in the question itself. I mean, editing your question post and modifying it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, it seems the path you mention is missing.